# Does the CLT apply to functions of two random samples, in particular f(X, Y) = X + Y?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

Say I have two i.i.d. samples X1,X2,...,Xn and Y1,Y2,...,Yn with population means E(X) and  E(Y), and population variance var(X) and var(Y). If I apply the CLT, then the scaled (by square root n) and centred (by the population mean) sample means of X and Y are distributed N(0, Var(X)) and N(0, Var(Y)).

I know that any function of X or Y, f(Xi) or f(Yi), is also i.i.d so I can apply the CLT again. But what about functions of both of them f(Xi,Yi). In particular f(Xi,Yi) = Xi + Yi and f(Xi,Yi) = Xi * Yi. Can I still apply the CLT? Can I only apply it in certain circumstances (like if I assume the two samples are also independent of each other)?

Thanks very much,

Daniel

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Without mutual independence you have absolutely no hope.

Comment: Define $Z_i=f(X_i,Y_i)$.  If $\{Z_i\}$ are i.i.d. with finite mean and variance (with $\sigma^2>0$), you can apply CLT.  They will be i.i.d. when $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. vectors.  For a fixed $i$, there is no need for $X_i$ to have the same distribution (or be independent of) $Y_i$.